# Is mold inside eggshells a sign they're unsafe to eat?

Tags: eggs, mold

Cooked (over-easy) a duck egg this morning. When cleaning up I noticed black mold inside the shell of the egg I had just eaten. Was it safe to eat?

Comment: You will find out quite soon. If we don't hear from you again, it was a yes ;). Do you have a picture of the egg shell?

Comment: Hello Cheri, your question is not answerable. You could just as well say, "I bought stock of company XYZ, will I get rich?". Food safety will only tell you under which circumstances there is 99.9999999% certainty that nothing will happen. Everything else (including obvious spoilage) falls under "we have no idea".

Comment: I think the best advice if you are worried is to seek medical advice from a trusted medical professional. If you still have the egg she'll they may be interested to do a culture or they may simply be able to identify it as is. They will be best able to help you to know the best course of action at this point.